# Как реализовать рекурсию

Tags: python, python-3.x

Подскажите, как можно сделать рекурсию или любое другое решение для получения значения. На выходе должен получить 1. Предоставлена тестовая функция:

```
  def recurs():
    some_dict = ["a", "g", "b"... n]
    dict_in_dict = {"a":{"g":{"b":{"c":{...n :1}}}}
    for key in some_dict:
      return recurs(dict_in_dict[key])
```

Comment: Опишите ожидаемый результат

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: вам срочно нужно прочитать про рекурсию. Во-первых, в рекурсивной функции должен быть параметр. Во-вторых, инициализируя при каждом вызове переменные одним и теми же значениями вы далеко не уедете. И в третьих, вам нужно разобраться что и откуда вы хотите доставить при каждом вызове функции.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```py
  some_dict = ["a", "g", "b"... n]
  dict_in_dict = {"a":{"g":{"b":{"c":{...n :1}}}}
  def recurs(some_dict, dict_in_dict):
    if not some_dict:
      return dict_in_dict
    key = some_dict[0]:
    return recurs(some_dict[1:], dict_in_dict[key])
```